# OpenCV Grid Area

Tags: c++, c, image-manipulation, opencv, area

I want to find the non-white area of an image from a camera using OpenCV. I can already find circles using images from my web cam. I want to make a grid or something so I can determine the percent of the image is not white. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find the percentage of pixels in your image which is not white, why don't you just count all the pixels which are not white and divide it by the total number of pixels in the image?

**Code in C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main()
{
    // Acquire the image (I'm reading it from a file);
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("image.bmp",1);

    int i,j,k;
    // Variables to store image properties
    int height,width,step,channels;
    uchar *data;
    // Variables to store the number of white pixels and a flag
    int WhiteCount,bWhite;

    // Acquire image unfo
    height    = img->height;
    width     = img->width;
    step      = img->widthStep;
    channels  = img->nChannels;
    data      = (uchar *)img->imageData;

    // Begin
    WhiteCount = 0;
    for(i=0;i<height;i++) 
    {
      for(j=0;j<width;j++) 
      { // Go through each channel of the image (R,G, and B) to see if it's equal to 255
        bWhite = 0;
        for(k=0;k<channels;k++)
        {   // This checks if the pixel's kth channel is 255 - it can be faster.
            if (data[i*step+j*channels+k]==255) bWhite = 1;
            else 
            {
                bWhite = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(bWhite == 1) WhiteCount++;
      }
    }       

    printf("Percentage: %f%%",100.0*WhiteCount/(height*width));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What would be a method of doing that?

Comment: Are you using OpenCV2.0 (i.e. the `Mat` class) or an older version (`IplImage*`,`CvArray*`,..)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cv::countNonZero` and subtract if your image is only black and white.